# How to make an exception to certain StyleCop rules?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suppress a StyleCop warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287656/how-to-suppress-a-stylecop-warning)

Currently I'm setting up StyleCop for our projects and I stumbled on one rule of StyleCop. It's about the SA1300 naming rule:

> SA1300: namespace names begin with an
>   upper-case letter: iCompanyName.

So my company starts with a lower-case letter. And various product names do also. Therefore, is there a possibility to add exceptions to this rule in the Settings.StyleCop file?

I'd like to prevent to write custom StyleCop rules using C#.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

**edit:**
I realize I should have noted that I don't actually want to disable/suppress the StyleCop rule completely. I'd just like to make some exceptions on this naming rule.

Comment: `my company starts with a lower-case letter` the easiest option is to switch to a company with style-cop compliant name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SA1300 rule is not configurable (at least in version 4.4).  If you don't like its behaviour and don't want to disable the rule entirely, you will need to use a substitute custom rule.  You might be able to find one available from a third-party such as the [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) project.  If not, you're pretty much stuck rolling your own...

Comment: Good suggestion to try the StyleCop+ project. However, doesn't really provide functionality to make naming rule exceptions. Guess I have to make my own rules, thought it should be possible within the config.

Comment: If you want the rule to be configurable, you could add a feature request at http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.  Personally (particularly as an API consumer), I don't think that namespace casing should be allowed to deviate from this rule, but ymmv...

Comment: Hi Monty. I am StyleCop+ author and, by its design, it offers extremely flexible naming rules. Different naming styles, prefixes, exceptions, abbreviations, complex words... this is all what StyleCop+ was created for. In your case, you could force, for example, all namespaces to be named as [PascalCase] OR "iYourCompany" (like an exception). Or, for example, [PascalCase] OR i[PascalCase] (i.e. allow any names starting with "i"). What I can agree about, that it may have lack of documentation - but it's being worked on. Feel free to contact me, I'll answer any questions with pleasure. Thank you!

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for your nice answer. I did gave it another shot and I managed to get it working the way I wanted it to!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it really not configurable? Warning stands "Remove the prefix or add it to the list of allowed prefixes.". Or the warning is wrong or there should be a list where a prefix can be added. **Where?** I could not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can suppress the message on a case by case basis as described on the StyleCop site - http://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rule%20Suppressions

Also, have a look at this question - [How to suppress a StyleCop warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287656/how-to-suppress-a-stylecop-warning)