# How to ignore Stylecop rule SP0100?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fxcop, stylecop

How to suppress Style Cop rule SP0100?

> Enumeration item name v2007 doesn't conform the specified style: SampleName, Sample_Name.

---

I tried following https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296152/284795

```
 [SuppressMessage("SP0100")]
```

But I get an error

> 'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure that you have the index of the name right?

[ElementsMustBeOrderedByAccess seems to be rule SA1202](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1202.html)

**EDIT**:

[You should check the Microsoft documentation for rule suppressions, which explains the constructor syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx).

OK, so it seems you are using a [StyleCop+](http://stylecopplus.codeplex.com/) rule - meaning that it is a bit of a pain to find the appropriate suppression data.

I have found the information for the ID in the [source XML](https://github.com/shuruev/StyleCopPlus/blob/master/StyleCopPlus/StyleCopPlusRules.xml) file for the rules, and, if I understand correctly, the category should be set to the full name of the class that exposes the rule, which is [`StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlusRules`](https://github.com/shuruev/StyleCopPlus/blob/master/StyleCopPlus/StyleCopPlusRules.cs).

Meaning that the minimal attribute declaration, in your case, would be:

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCopPlus.StyleCopPlusRules","SP0100:AdvancedNamingRules")]
```