# How to declare a nullable array type in C#?

Tags: c#, nullable, stylecop

I am working with multi dimensional arrays that can store null values.

I am declaring one of my array as follows :

```
public Size?[,] CellSize { get; set; }
```

However when I compile it, StyleCop gives an error 
SA0102 : CSharp.CsParser : A syntax error has been discovered in file ....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the declaration, I'm guessing that this may be a StyleCop bug.

Comment: What is `Size`? It might be a good idea to tell us the type.

Comment: Ok then how can I supress this error?

Comment: @Svek It is System.Drawing.Size

Comment: [How to suppress a StyleCop warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287656/how-to-suppress-a-stylecop-warning)