# Which is better style, an ambiguous, notated, or renamed parameter?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

Stylecop seems inconsistent in naming parameters or perhaps I'm missing something?

I have

```
    Movement movement;

    public void SetMovement(Movement movement)
    {
        this.movement = movement;
    }
```

which complains about my parameter hiding a field, which is understandable.
Then I try to name the parameter differently

```
    public void SetMovement(Movement _movement)
    {
        this.movement = _movement;
    }
```

which will complain about underscores and Hungarian notations, etc.

It seems the only way to satisfy stylecop in this case would be to name the parameter something different like

```
    public void SetMovement(Movement movementParameter)
    {
        this.movement = movementParameter;
    }
```

Which of these would be considered the best 'style'?

Comment: I think most people would do `this.movement = movement;`. If you're strictly following StyleCop's rule here, you would need to name your parameter something different (I'd choose something like `requestedMovement` rather than `movementParameter`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I would did (and I actually do) just the same thing you did: calling the parameter just the same as private field.
That code is pretty clear to me, despite StyleCop judgement 
In other situations I use different names for parameters and equivalent fields, e.g. when the meaning of the passed parameters (and so its name) changes when it is injected in a method.
I'm not a StyleCop guy, but I think you can say it to not bother you using an attribute, a special comment or so 
Maybe like this: [How to suppress a StyleCop warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287656/how-to-suppress-a-stylecop-warning)