# How to disable/ignore StyleCop warnings for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I have a SyleCop.Variable warning that I want to disable for my project:

BT1000 : StyleCop.Variable : Member variables should be prefixed by underscore followed by a lowercase letter.

It's about the following line of code:

```
private static readonly FilterContext FilterContext = new FilterContext(Filter.Test, null, 0, null);
```

The StyleCop suggests to be like this:

```
private static readonly FilterContext _filterContext = new FilterContext(Filter.Test, null, 0, null);
```

Which conflicts with the C# standards.

https://techwiki/gaming/index.php?title=CSharp_Standards

Do you know how a specific warning can be disable and ignored in the Visual Studio 2017 ?

Comment: Duplicate with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287656/how-to-suppress-a-stylecop-warning)

Comment: You sure it is BT1000? I haven't seen that prefix before.

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Comment: Could you perhaps show a screenshot of the warning? Do you have any plugins / extensions installed in VS 2017?

Comment: I have only ReSharper installed for my VS2017

Comment: Any luck with the screenshot?

Comment: Does the warning go away if you disable Resharper?

Comment: It doesn't go away after disabling Resharper but I found a way to fix it when removed "static" and changed it to "private readonly FilterContext _filterContext". It is just annoying when you can't disable this type of warnings.